# how to change case of Nextjs generated prisma types from snake_case to camelCase

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, prisma

i have fullstack application build with nextjs and prisma ORM

```
"next": "12.3.0"
"prisma": "^4.5.0"
```

basically i want to change the case of my types from *snake_case* to *caselCase* to match front-end part. also would be nice to make types not nullable, but that not the main issue here

in the example you can see prisma.schema file model

```
model match {
  id                              Int
  tournament_id                   Int?
  player1_id                      Int?
  player2_id                      Int?
  comment                         String?
  is_completed                    Boolean?
  stage                           Int?
  start_date                      DateTime?   @db.Date
  winner_id                       String?
  score                           String?
  player3_id                      Int?
  player4_id                      Int?
}
```

and corresponding ts file looks like this

```
export type match = {
id: number
tournament_id: number | null
player1_id: number | null
player2_id: number | null
comment: string | null
is_completed: boolean | null
stage: number | null
start_date: Date | null
winner_id: string | null
score: string | null
player3_id: number | null
player4_id: number | null
}
```

match = {
id: number
tournamentId: number
player1Id: number
player2Id: number
comment: string
isCompleted: boolean
stage: number
startDate: Date
winnerId: string
score: string | null
player3id: number
player4Id: number
}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this by using [`@map`](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#map)

```
model match {
  id           Int       @unique @map("id")
  tournamentId Int?      @map("tournament_id")
  player1Id    Int?      @map("player1_id")
  player2Id    Int?      @map("player2_id")
  comment      String?   @map("comment")
  isCompleted  Boolean?  @map("is_completed")
  stage        Int?      @map("stage")
  startDate    DateTime? @map("start_date") @db.Date
  winnerId     String?   @map("winner_id")
  score        String?   @map("score")
  player3Id    Int?      @map("player3_id")
  player4Id    Int?      @map("player4_id")
}
```

Comment: thx a lot! missed that docs section....